# Flattening and remove keys from array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I turn a multidimensional array like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_id] => 1941 ) )
```

Into

```
Array ( 1941, ..., ..., ... )
```

I have tried flattening the array, but the keys are still there.

```
$a = Array();
foreach($result as $r) $a[] = $r['entry_id'];
```

I am using PHP.

Comment: Can you add the language you are working in please?

Comment: Added. I am using PHP.

Comment: Hmm..I tried your code, it is doing exactly the thing you want.

Comment: I get: Array ( [0] => 1941 )

Comment: Yes me too, and that is the correct output. You wont get something like Array ( 1941 )  because of the indexes but you can hide indexes when outputing the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast and simple solution if you have PHP 5.5+

```
$result = array_column($yourArray, 'entry_id');
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: But OP is not asking for a fast solution. Your solution leads to the same results as OP has gotten.